# How to return filtered list from another list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

On my application I'm creating another view for statistics. The table in database has ScheduleId, Line, OperatorId, Shift, Function. From all records in db I want to take all employees from one ScheduleId. I do filter them by 'Working Line' however I need total number of employees.
Any help how to achieve this?

.cshtml

```
  @foreach (var schedule in @Model.AllSchedules.DistinctBy(x => x.ScheduleId))
        {
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Line</td>
                        <td>Emploees</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@schedule.Line</td>
                        <td>@schedule.OperatorId</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> however I need total number of employees

outside of the loop, it will return only 1 number
:

```
total number of employees:@Model.AllSchedules.DistinctBy(x => x.OperatorId).Count()
```

@Maria's solution   inside the loop, foreach line total number of employees:

```
@Model.AllSchedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleId == schedule.ScheduleId).Count()
```

Comment: If I add that code outside of the loop, it will return only 1 number.  I need foreach line total number of employees. But I found the solution, inside the loop:  var totalNumOfEmp = @Model.AllSchedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleId == schedule.ScheduleId).Count()

Answer (score 0):

If you do a [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) rather than `.DistinctBy()` in your `foreach`, you can simply check the `.Count()` of the group to count the number of employees with the given `ScheduleId`.

The `Line` and `OperatorId` then need to be read from the first element in the group.

```
@foreach (var scheduleGroup in @Model.AllSchedules.GroupBy(x => x.ScheduleId))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Line</td>
                <td>Operator ID</td>
                <td>Employees</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>@scheduleGroup.First().Line</td>
                <td>@scheduleGroup.First().OperatorId</td>
                <td>@scheduleGroup.Count()</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```